# timeout for function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, timeout

```
function getNames(){
    // some code
}
```

This function can be done in one second, but sometimes it freezes itself and html block on the page (ajax inside) on infinite time.

I would like to have time limit for this function. If it doesn't finish in ten seconds, then abort it.

How to do this?

Comment: have you got "async:true," as an ajax parameter?

Comment: It might help if we knew what the //Some Code was...

Comment: You might consider using web workers if //some code is something that might take a long time sometimes (like waiting for large amounts of information from a slow server). That way you have no blocking in the main page.

Comment: @tiagoboldt I'm not good at javascript, can you give an example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really easy with jQuery 1.5’s [deferred promises](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

The following example creates a Deferred and sets two timer-based functions to either *resolve* or *reject* the Deferred after a random interval. Whichever one fires first “wins” and will call one of the callbacks. The second timeout has no effect since the Deferred is already complete (in a resolved or rejected state) from the first timeout action.

```
// Create a Deferred and return its Promise
function asyncEvent() {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.resolve('hurray');
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.reject('sorry');
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    return dfd.promise();
}

// Attach a done and fail handler for the asyncEvent
$.when( asyncEvent() ).then(
    function(status) {
        alert( status + ', things are going well' );
    },
    function(status) {
        alert( status + ', you fail this time' );
    }
);
```

You can easily modify this example to suit your needs:

```
// Create a Deferred and return its Promise
function asyncEvent() {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    // Your asynchronous code goes here

    // When the asynchronous code is completed, resolve the Deferred:
    dfd.resolve('success');

    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.reject('sorry');
    }, 10000); // 10 seconds
    return dfd.promise();
}

// Attach a done and fail handler for the asyncEvent
$.when( asyncEvent() ).then(
    function(status) {
        alert( status + ', things are going well' );
    },
    function(status) {
        alert( status + ', you fail this time' );
    }
);
```

Comment: how to use it with my function? where should I paste the code. reject/resolve - status text?

Comment: @Happy Resolve the Deferred when the asynchronous code is completed, e.g. `dfd.resolve('success');`. (Added this to the answer, too.) You should allow `getNames` to accept a callback function that does this.

Comment: sorry again, how to use it with getNames()?

Comment: @Happy: I just told you in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the function itself that's grinding away, just set a timer and either `return` or `throw` if it exceeds your maximum time period.

If, on the other hand, if the delay is caused by the AJAX request not returning, and you are using `$.ajax()`, you can always set the `timeout` setting. It should kill the request. Note that you need to avoid relying on the `success` callback, since it only gets called if the request succeeds. Instead, use `complete` callback to watch for failures. It will tell you if an error occurred. According to the documentation, this is available in 1.4 onwards. I'm not sure about pre-1.4, but I think it worked in 1.3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can go with Web Workers if //some code is something that might take a long time sometimes (like waiting for large amounts of information from a slow server). That will allow background processing without locking the main page. Note that not all browsers support it yet.

You can find a nice introduction [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/workers/basics/).