# Is it possible to call WebBrowser.InvokeScript async from an WPF application?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I want to call a JavaScript function in a hosted WebBrowser. My JavaScript function is slow (in UI not retrieving data or ajax) and I want to make my WPF interface responsive while the JavaScript function is being executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call your JavaScript function asynchronously (e.g., upon a timer), but asynchrony doesn't assume multithreading, the function will still be executed entirely on the main UI thread. And you cannot use a separate thread for this, because the underlying `WebBrowser` ActiveX control is an STA COM object.

If you really have to perform a lengthy UI update work inside your JavaScript function, the right way of doing this would be to throttle the update logic and execute it in multiple steps, each step asynchronously, to keep the UI thread responsive. You can do this using [`setTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or jQuery's [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). A more well-structured approach would be to use jQuery Deferreds, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5244075/1768303).

Answer (score 1):

We solved our problem  somehow with a trick, might be useful for others. 
After a call to WebBrowser we start a new window in a new UI thread and put our new window on the previous window (which its thread is busy doing JavaScript calculation in WebBrowser) , so we are able to somehow show progress-bar and loading page while doing heavy drawing in our html .