# Understanding jQuery.Deferred in the context of jQuey.AJAX (again)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I concede that, despite hours of reading and attempting, I am fundamentally unable to grasp something about Deferred promises and asynchrony in general.

The goal on my end is real, real simple: send some data to the server, and react to the contents of the response conditionally.

The response will always be a JSON object with `save` and `error` keys:

```
{ "save": true, "error":false} 
// or
{ "save" : false, 
  "error" : "The server has run off again; authorities have been notifed."}
```

I have tried dozens and dozens of variations from the jQuery API, from other stackexchange answers, from tutorials, etc.. The examples all seem concerned with local asynchronous activity. When I need is some ability to be made aware when the AJAX request has either finished and returned a response I can inspect and make decisions about, or else to know that it's failed. Below, I've used comments to explain what I think is happening so someone can show me where I'm failing.

I *know* this is a repost; I am, apprently, worse than on average at grasping this.

```
var postData = {"id":7, "answer":"Ever since I went to Disneyland..."};

    /* when(), as I understand it, should fire an event to be 
       responded to by then() when it's contents have run their course */

var result = $.when(
       /* here I believe I'm supposed to assert what must complete 
          before the when() event has fired and before any chained 
          functions are subsequently called */

             /* this should return a jqXHR object to then(), which is,
                I'd thought, a queue of functions to call, in order, 
                UPON COMPLETION of the asynchronous bit */
             $.post("my/restful/url", postData))
    .then( function() {
        /* since "this" is the jqXHR object generated in the $.post()
           call above, and since it's supposed to be completed by now,
           it's data key should be populated by the server's response—right? */
        return this.data;
    });

    // alas, it isn't
    console.log(result.data);
    // >> undefined
```

Most examples I can find discuss a timeout function; but this seems, as I understand, to be a failsafe put in place to arbitrarily decide when the asynchronous part is said to have failed, rather than a means of stalling for time so the request can complete. Indeed, if all we can do is just wait it out, how's that any different from a synchronous request?

I'll even take links to a *new* read-mes, tutorials, etc. if they cover the material in a different way, use something other than modified examples from the jQuery API, or otherwise help this drooling idiot through the asynchronous mirk; here's where I've been reading to date:

[jQuery API: Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)
[JQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/ajax-deferreds) 
[jQuery Deferreds promises asynchronous bliss (blog)](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/javascript/jquery-deferreds-promises-asynchronous-bliss/)
[StackOverflow: timeout for function (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244022/timeout-for-function-jquery)

---

**Update**

This is in response to @Kevin B below:

I tried this:

```
var moduleA = {
        var moduleB = {
                    postData: {"id":7, "answer":"Ever since I went to Disneyland..."};
                    save: function() {
                       return $.post("path/to/service", postData, null, "JSON");
                    }
        };
        var result = this.moduleB.save();
        result.done(function(resp) {
            if (resp.saved == true) {
                // never reached before completion
                console.log("yahoo");
            } else {
                console.log("Error: " + resp.error);
                // >> undefined
            }
        });
```

}

Comment: you can't `console.log(result.data);` where you did. you just can't. stop trying. !! you must interact with the data inside of the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating your code. You cannot get the data to outside of the callback, no matter how many deferred/promises you create/use (your sample creates 3 different deferred objects!)

Use the done callback.

```
var postData = {"id":7, "answer":"Ever since I went to Disneyland..."};
$.post("my/restful/url", postData).done(function (result) {
    console.log(result.save, result.error);
});
```

Comment: I could swear I've tried this already several time, but I'm off to confirm that just in case. Thanks for indulging me, I know the pros start to twitch every time someone asks a question about this!

Comment: The most common cause for a question like this is someone trying to make a function that returns a value from an ajax request. That simply won't work in javascript without making the ajax request synchronous **(which is a very bad thing to do to your gui)**

Comment: I see it now, thanks so much. Can I bounce a question off you? In the context of my program, it matters which response comes from the server; that is, when the call is all said and done, some conditional activity gets started. The call is occuring inside Object B, which is a property of ParentObject A. A calls B.asyncFunc() like so: `A.func() { A.B.asyncFunc();}`, so my goal is return to A from it's child a (modified) response from the server. If it's a big thing to explain, then nvm, but broadly, since returning from $.ajax() won't fly, how does one achieve something like this?

Comment: You simply return $.post to A, then within A use .done to get the result.

Comment: I think you just blew my mind; like this(ish): `A.func() {var postResp = A.B.asyncFunc(); postResp.done(function(respData) { //now A can inspect and make decisions with respData?});`

Comment: Correct, as long as asyncFunc has return $.post(...)

Comment: I'm probably asking a lot, but I've added to my original question my understanding of you're suggesting (well it's pared down a lot from my actual context, but that's just to save on bloat). Predictably, I am still doing this wrong. I don't, however, understand why. : /

Comment: That *does* work, but that, I've independently confirmed, is a consequence of Chrome duping me; Chrome waits for completion to print within some allotted time, so yeah, `console.log(resp)` works; but operations on the expected keys of `resp` still don't work at the time I'm making the call. :(

Comment: if the console.log is inside the .done, it wont' happen until after the completion anyway...

Comment: Here it is working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PNz5B/1/) (with simulated $.post and slight modifications to your snippet so that it's valid javascript)

Comment: Haha you prince of a man, thanks—but you forgot the link to your fiddle!

Comment: Nice. In my circumstance, for some reason, I had to use `complete()` rather than `.done()`, but all the same I'm on my feet. Truly thanks a  million.

Comment: Try using .always, .complete is deprecated. If .done isn't firing, .fail likely is.

Comment: Noted... and disconcerting. But if I can't get it from here, I've no business trying. Thanks again.

Comment: LOL. And now to put this to bed for good, I'm just an idiot; `complete()` returns the responseObject, whereas done() returns the response string. My code had been written for one and receiving the other and I guess I've just gone error-message blind from saturation. This puppy be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of both asynchronous requests, the Promise pattern, and Javascripts mechanism of passing functions as an argument.

To understand what's really happening in your code I suggest you use a debugger and set some breakpoints in the code. Or, alternatively, add some console.logs in your code. This way you can see the flow of the program and might understand it better. Also be sure to log the arguments of the function you pass as an argument in the then()-method, so you understand what is passed.

Comment: This is useful advice, I'd done it plenty, it was really the idea that you fundamentally cannot return anything useful from a call to $.ajax that I was missing, in tandem with a strategy for getting all my work done inside a .done() or .success() or whatever. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

ok you got it half right. the problem is that when you execute the console.log the promised is not yet fulfilled the asynchronous nature of the promises allows the code to execute before that ajax operation is done. also result is a deferred not a value, you need to handle your promised with .done instead of .then if you wish to return a value otherwise you'll continue passing promises.

so that said

```
var result={};
  $.when(
      $.post("my/restful/url", postData))
        .done( function(data) {
        result.data=data;
  });
// here result is an object and data is a undefined since the promised has no yet been resolve.
console.log(result.data);
```

Comment: Now, `result.data` is undefined. :) You're logging it before the ajax request completes.

Comment: yes and it will stay that way untill the promise is fulfilled. the idea here is to demostrate how promises work, not to log the value, of the response.